# Obtener valor de un input de HTML y guardarlo en una variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy queriendo que el usuario ingrese unos datos por in input (Va a ser con "comas"), lo almaceno en una variable y lo paso a un array.

Me funciona todo, excepto el hecho de obtener el input de html y guardarlo en una variable externa a la función:

```
<form name="formPalabraas" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="prod" id="inputPalabras">

<button onclick="subPalabras()">Prueba</button>
```

y el codigo Javascript que tengo es:

```js
var verFueraDeLaFuncion = [];    
function subPalabras(){
   palabrasDelUsuario = document.getElementById("inputPalabras").value;
   verFueraDeLaFuncion = palabrasDelUsuario;
   alert(verFueraDeLaFuncion);
};
```

Si hago un alert de la variable `verFueraDeLaFuncion` dentro la función `subPalabras()`, sale bien. Ahora, si lo hago fuera de esa función al alert, me sale vacio.

En si quiero:

- Enviar datos de un input a una variable Javascript
- Que esta variable la guarde para utilizarla en cualquier parte del codigo
- Poder mostrarla

Cualquier dato me sirve. Muchas gracias.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el usuario teclee una unica cadena de caracteres compuestas por palabras con una "COMA", por ejemplo: "palabra1, palabra2, palabra3"

Yo a esa cadena la quiero convertir en un array, donde cada item sea una palabra usando la funcion split();

y asi obtener-> `verFueraDeLaFuncion = ["palabra1","palabra2","palabra3"];` No se si se entiende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar localstorage, para no causarte problemas solo limpia cuando cargues la pagina:

```html
<form>
<script>
const guardar= function(nombre,valor){ 
window.localStorage.setItem(nombre, valor);}
const obtener= function(nombre) 
{
 return window.localStorage.getItem(nombre);
}
const limpiarStorage=function()
{
 window.localStorage.clear();
}

limpiarStorage();
const subPalabras=function subPalabras(){
  event.preventDefault();
   palabrasDelUsuario = document.getElementById("inputPalabras").value;
   guardar("palabrasDelUsuario",palabrasDelUsuario);
  // alert(verFueraDeLaFuncion);

};

function muestraPalabras()
{
  alert(obtener("palabrasDelUsuario"));
 return false;
}
 
</script>

<input type="text" name="prod" id="inputPalabras">

<button onclick="subPalabras()">Guarda</button>

<button onclick="muestraPalabras()">Muestra</button>

</form>
```

Comment: asi es con local storage si quitas la parte de limpiar storage el valor de la variable permanece en tu sitio solo debes tener cuidado con las  actualizaciones de tu valor,  ahora var nombres= 'Harry,John,Clark,Peter,Rohn,Alice';
var nombresArray = nombres.split(','); //

Comment: Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el usuario teclee una unica cadena de caracteres compuestas por palabras con una "COMA", por ejemplo: "palabra1, palabra2, palabra3"

Yo a esa cadena la quiero convertir en un array, donde cada item sea una palabra. De esta forma y siguiendo el ejemplo quiero ahcer en la funcion muestraPalabras() :

verFueraDeLaFuncion = obtener("palabrasDelUsuario");

y con la funcion split(); haria el resto, para asi obtener

verFueraDeLaFuncion = ["palabra1","palabra2","palabra3"];

No se si se entiende.

Answer (score 5):

Tu codigo funciona bien, el problema es que estas imprimiendo la variable antes de asignarle valor.  Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas que el valor tambien puede imprimirse fuera de la funcion.

```js
var verFueraDeLaFuncion = [];    
    function subPalabras(){
                    palabrasDelUsuario = document.getElementById("inputPalabras").value;
        verFueraDeLaFuncion = palabrasDelUsuario;
alert(verFueraDeLaFuncion);
                };
                
function otraFuncion() {
  alert(verFueraDeLaFuncion);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="prod" id="inputPalabras">

<button onclick="subPalabras()">Prueba</button>
<button onclick="otraFuncion()">Fuera</button>
```